# Understanding the sum of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

I am currently learning probability theory. I have two questions:

I would like to know through an example what is meant by the sum of random variables (r.v.). To make things simple let consider only two r.v., $X$ and $Y$. Let $X$ represent the weight of individuals of some population and $Y$ their respective ages.

So what does the sum and the mean value would mean in this case given the fact that the quality of the two r.v. is different ?

My second question is: given the expression $\mathbb P(|X_n|> na)$ i would like to understand why it tends to $0$ if $n\to\infty$ and $a>0$ ?

Thanks for your comments.

Comment: That's not a very natural sum of random variables but somebody may well use it for something.  But all it really means is that if you add a person's weight and age you get a random number, and that random number can be decomposed into the sum of two random numbers, weight and age.  That's all it means, nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 0):

First question:

I think you chose strange random variables, as explicated by @GregoryGrant. Start with discrete random variables. In fact, start with $X$ and $Y$ both dice rolls.

Then the $X+Y$ is just the value of a roll in Monopoly (or any other game where you roll two dice and add the face values). If you're well-versed in dice games, you know the mean value of $X+Y$ is 7; you should try and figure this out from basic probability rules to get some practice.

As to your second question, I think it's just a matter of understanding exactly what is meant by all of the symbols in your expression, so let's just parse things:

- $\mathbb{P}[\cdot]$ means the probability of $\cdot$, i.e., how frequently the event within the bracket occurs, according to the distribution of some random variable, in your case $X_n$.
- $na, a>0$ is just an expression that grows without bound as $n\rightarrow\infty$
- $|X_n|>na$ is an event--it means that the random variable $X_n$ realized to a "large" value, a value that gets larger and larger as $n$ increases.

Taken together, then, the expression $\mathbb{P}[|X_n|>na]$ represents the likelihood that $|X_n|$ realizes to a very large value. As $n$ gets larger, we expect it to be more and more unlikely that such realizations occur* . In other words, the fact that that expression tends to 0 is another way of saying that "the probability of everything happening is 1".

*This isn't necessarily the case, and it would be easy to cook up examples of sequences ${X_n}$ of variables for which that expression doesn't hold; this is something to keep in mind, but the context should make it clear whether this is something to worry about.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Are you refering to the case where  Xn diverges, so that the equation would not hold any longer ?

Comment: Correct. I'm not sure your context, but I have a feeling that expression came up in the context of a theorem--that that is a condition for a theorem to hold. But regardless, for any _fixed_ random variable, $\lim\limits_{N\rightarrow\infty} \mathbb{P}[|X|>N]=0$. The problem here is sort of like uniform convergence--the sequence of $X_n$ may not be such that the particular bound $na$ is enough to "uniformly" bound the "tail weight" of the sequence.

Comment: Deleted my answer since this one is better.